# Date rollover failure in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

iOS allows date rollover for date such as 30th feb,Nov 31st to nearest future date such as Mar 1st,Dec 1st in m my case. The above works with the date of the format mm/dd or dd/mm.But when dateFromString is used to extract date form string,I'm facing a issue in xcode as below:

```
NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

The output in Xcode 5 is 'null' for `myDate`.

But interestingly, the code works in an online Objective-C compiler like http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php: 
this is giving me the date as "2014-03-01 00:00:00 -0600" as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the Year 2014  there is no 29 Feb.@Deepak

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I am aware of it .Actually ,the logic is related to date rollover(so the year 2014,a non leap year) and I'm testing the possibilities such as 2/29 ,2/30 ,11/31 etc. They all rollover to the next immediate date. But when I use dateFromString method,it isn't working xcode.(but as mentioned it is working in a online compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Because 2014 is not a leap year . :)

make year = 2016

```
NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2016";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

output is

> 2016-02-28 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: Actually ,the logic is related to date rollover(so the year 2014,a non leap year) and I'm testing the possibilities such as 2/29 ,2/30 ,11/31 etc. They all rollover to the next immediate date. But when I use dateFromString method,it isn't working xcode.(but as mentioned it is working in a online compiler)